# Control the index of an byte[] array

Tags: c#, arrays

Is it possible to control the index position in a `byte[]` array? In the following code I expect the return value of `value1` enters in the first seven bytes in `join` and the return value of `value2` enters  in the 8 9 10 11 position sequentially. But this is not happening. The first seven bytes are lost because the index is in 0 position always. How to control the index position?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] join = new byte[15];
        join = value1(); //seven byte enters. 
        join = value2(); //next four byte enters.
                               // 'join' should now have eleven bytes. 
        string a = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(join);
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static byte[] value1() 
    {

        string first = "welcome";
        byte[] f = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(first);
        return f;// seven byte returning.

    }

    public static byte[] value2() 
    {
        string second = "home";
        byte[] s = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(second);
        return s;//four byte returning.
    }
```

I know the code can be reorganize using `Array.Copy()` or `Buffer.BlockCopy()`. But these two methods are time consuming if the code runs 100,000 times or more. I'm looking forward to avoid these two methods and get the return values directly inside `join`.

---Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value1` and `value2` methods *returns* a byte array, while you presumably want to append the values to the existing `join` array.

You can use `Array.Copy` (or `Buffer.BlockCopy`) to put the returned values inside `join` array :

```
var v1 = value1(); //seven byte returned. 
var v2 = value2(); //next four byte returned.
var join = new byte[v1.Length + v2.Length];

// copy v1 at index 0 of join
Array.Copy(v1, 0, join, 0, v1.Length); 
// copy v2 at index v1.Length of join
Array.Copy(v2, 0, join, v1.Length, v2.Length);
```

---

**EDIT :**

I did a small benchmark to test the performances of the proposed methods, and here's the result (with 6 millions of repetions for each method) :

```
Benchmark results (6000000 repetitions) :
JoinCodeUsingArrayCopy       : 4076021 ticks (1304 ms)
JoinCodeUsingSetItems        : 4873634 ticks (1559 ms)
JoinCodeUsingList            : 8729925 ticks (2793 ms)
JoinCodeUsingBufferBlockCopy : 3665075 ticks (1172 ms)
```

Benchmark code [here](http://pastebin.com/SThd9nGF).

As you can see `Array.Copy/Buffer.BlockCopy` are the fastest methods, even if the method using list is not much much slower (we're talking about 1.5 second of difference on 6 million iterations after all).
Probably I would go for the list method because is the *cleanest* since it does not require to work directly with offsets/start indexes.

Comment: I said I want to avoid Array.Copy() because it slows down my code.

Comment: Array.Copy is usually the fastest way to fill an array (even faster than looping on values)... it seems really really strange to me that it's slowing down your code... I would really be interested in seeing this code...

Comment: when the code runs 100,000 or more times then I'll have 200,000 or more Array.Copy()s running in my code. Can you imagine how much time it takes to do that? That's way I wish to get the value directly instead of using two Array.Copy() methods.

Comment: If you don't use `Array.Copy` you will use another way to put your returned values into the join array, for example the `SetItems` method shown in the other answer, and you will call it 200,000 times as well. Do you think the code in the other answer performs less operations than `Array.Copy` ? It does *exactly* the same number of operations but probably Array.Copy is slighlty more optimized.

Comment: give me some time to test and see which one is more faster in my actual code. :)

Comment: Yes, I also did the testing with the 'List' code and it is making my actual code 3 times slower than before(which uses Array.Copy). So this settles that I'm stack with the best efficient """"Array.Copy()"""" . No way to reduce time.

Comment: You should really think to post your real code (using Array.Copy). Maybe some optimization that escaped to you could be found by the SO community ;)

Comment: can do a one more little thing? run Buffer.BlockCopy() as well. Just want to see whether Array.Copy is faster then Buffer.BlockCopy or not.

Comment: well, the  difference between posted code and actual code, the value1() and value2() methods is huge and does more complex operations . In 1MB input, these two methods run 131,074 times each.  I can't post the actual code its over 500 lines.

Comment: So Buffer.BlockCopy() it is. -------thanks so much. its time to remove all the Array.Copy()s.

Comment: @Giliweed: Yes, Buffer.BlockCopy is slightly faster than Array.Copy. I tend not to use it, since the offsets are in num. of bytes and not num. of slots of the array and so you need to be more careful in computing them. In this case there's no difference since you have an array of bytes ;)

Comment: I had to delete my comment because it a silly question. Everything is clear to me now. Thanks so much for the time testing. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do what you want, but you have to be careful. This [GetBytes overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c20ss51h(v=vs.110).aspx) lets you specify the byte array into which the bytes will be copied, and the index at which they will be copied. So, in your example, it would look like this:

```
    byte[] join = new byte[15];
    int ix = 0;
    ix = ix + Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(first, 0, first.Length, join, ix);
    ix = ix + Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(second, 0, second.Length, join, ix);
    string a = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(join, 0, ix);
```

The `ix` variable here keeps track of the total number of bytes that are encoded.

You have to be careful here to allocate enough bytes in your `join` array, and you have to keep track of the number of bytes encoded because with UTF-8 (and many other encodings) a single character could require multiple bytes.

You'll also want to see the [GetString overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3(v=vs.110).aspx) that lets you specify the starting position in the array and the number of bytes.

If you want to write methods that do this like your `value1` and `value2` methods, you'll have to pass the byte array and the array index to the methods. And those methods will have to return the number of bytes they encoded, or they'll have to add that value to the index and return the new index.

Comment: Your code looks interesting but right now the main issue is time. I was wrong at first and thought Array.Copy() was slowing down my code. But then I saw it is the second fastest method and thanks to digEmAll I saved a few seconds by using Buffer.BlockCopy(). From digEmAll's answer, if your code runs faster than Buffer.BlockCopy() I might accept it. :)

Comment: @Giliweed: On the face of it, my code *should* be faster because it writes the bytes directly to the destination array rather than writing to an intermediate array and then copying to the destination. It's up to you to do the benchmark, if it's that important. But if this isn't the bottleneck, then you're wasting your time optimizing it.

Comment: +1 : This should be definitely faster than other methods, since it saves some arrays allocation. As you said, the only drawback is you need to preallocate an initial array making an assumption on the maximum byte array length...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of assigning items of your array, you are throwing away the  `new byte[15]` and assigning it to new array. You can try using `List<byte>` first then convert it to an array:

```
var byteList = new List<byte>(15);

byteList.AddRange(value1());
byteList.AddRange(value2());

byte[] join = byteList.ToArray();
```

Another alternative is to create an extension method for your array, something like this:

```
public static void SetItems<T>(this T[] source, int startIndex, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
     // I omitted the checks (index, length, null etc.) but you should add them
     int i = startIndex;

     foreach(var item in items)
          source[i++] = item;
}
```

Then call it:

```
byte[] join = new byte[15];
join.SetItems(0, value1());
join.SetItems(4, value2());
```

This should be faster than first option because it doesn't create a list but it requires you to know the `startIndex`, in this case it shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: And another approach: `IEnumerable<byte> byteEnumerable = value1(); byteEnumerable = byteEnumerable.Concat(value2());`

Comment: Is it faster then 'Array.Copy()' or 'Buffer.BlockCopy()' if the code runs 100,000? The code which is more  time efficient matters.

Comment: @Giliweed - for most people, *correct* is the first thing you should optimize for, before *speed*.

Comment: why did you give '<T>' after SetItems is it something special? what does 'T[]' represents?

Comment: @Giliweed I make it [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).So it will work for all one-dimensional arrays, e.g. int[], short[], string[]

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I agree with you. And I'm not saying I want to do any incorrect coding. I just want a faster solution then Array.Copy(). In my actual code which runs over 100,000 times and  500,000 Array.Copy()s are running there. I'm just looking for an alternative of Array.Copy() and Buffer.BlockCopy().

Comment: "var byteList = new List<byte>(15);" --- can I make it public static so that other classes can access it?

Comment: OMG! your first code is 3 time slower then Array.Copy()!!!!! Can't accept that. hope the second one works...

Comment: when join is in main() , how do you call SetItems from join? "join.SetItems(0, value1());" --- trying to do this but after "." no method name SetItems is there and its not even suppose to be there. So how did you call it? join is not a class its an array. how does and array calls a static method?

Comment: @Giliweed it is an extension method put it inside a **public** and **static** class